# How to make all arguments have the same number of values?

Tags: rust, command-line-interface, command-line-arguments, clap

I'm building a CLI that will be used like this:

```
$ my_cli command aa aa -- bb bb
```

Arguments `aa aa` and `bb bb` will be collected into separated `Vec<String>`s. Let's call them `vec_a` and `vec_b`. I need both vectors to be the same length. This is what I tried in order to verify that the user gives the same number of values for both arguments:

```
use clap::{Parser, Subcommand};

// --snip--    

#[derive(Parser)]
#[clap(author, version, about)]
pub struct Cli {
    /// Operation to perform
    #[clap(subcommand)]
    pub command: Subcommands,
}

#[derive(Subcommand)]
pub enum Subcommands {
    // --snip--
    /// does something with vec_a and vec_b. Both must have the same length.
    Rebuild {
        /// Reads vec_a
        #[clap(value_parser, required(true))]
        vec_a: Vec<String>,
        /// Reads vec_b
        #[clap(
            value_parser,
            required(true),
            number_of_values=vec_a.len())]
        vec_b: Vec<String>,
    },
}
// --snip--
```

I get this error:

```
~/my_cli$ cargo run -- rebuild aa aa -- bb bb

error[E0425]: cannot find value `vec_a` in this scope
   |
   |             number_of_values=vec_a.len())]
   |                              ^^^^^ not found in this scope
```

So, how do I check that both arguments have the same length?

Maybe this could be expanded to a more general question: How do I read an argument from the derive properties of another argument?

Comment: I don't think there's a way to do this with clap, but you can always assert that condition yourself after clap has parsed the arguments.

Comment: If the elements from one array are meant to correspond to the other array, you might want to consider a mapping syntax like `aa=bb cc=dd ee=ff` instead.